# high precision calculation in numpy

Tags: numpy, precision

How to perform high precision calculation in numpy? 
By high precision I mean 100 precision in decimal.

Comment: Python has `Decimal` for this purpose, but NumPy has only standard datatypes like `np.float32` and `np.float64`.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Do you know if the Decimal is as fast as Numpy?

Comment: It's built on "normal" Python, so you have to run loops over the elements which will be much smaller as NumPy, I guess. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy doesn't have arbitrary floating-point precision. You'll want to use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) from the standard library, or a third-party library like [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/). Both of those libraries use C extensions for their internal calculations, so they should be fairly fast.

Comment: mpmath uses pure Python unless gmpy is installed.